# Transparent background for identification of 0 and 1 in a MATLAB figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I've sunlight and eclipse detection in my code. I'd like to highlight sunlight and eclipse detection in every plot I'm generating.

Suppose

```
sun_avail = 0; % means spacecraft is in eclipse
sun_avail = 1; % means spacecraft is in sunlit
```

I've set of variables (vectors (X,Y,Z)) needed to be plot in matlab figure which I'd do like this

```
fig = figure();
set(fig, 'name', 'Quaternions', 'NumberTitle', 'off');
subplot(4,1,1);
plot(t,Qp(:,1),'b','linewidth',2);
title('Quaternions wrt ref frame selected','fontweight','b')
hold on;plot(t,q_dp(:,1),'-.m','linewidth',2);
grid;zoom;
legend('Gyro Q Attitude (Actual Gyro)','Body Q Attitude (Ideal Gyro)');
xlabel('time in secs','fontweight','b')
ylabel('q1','fontweight','b')

subplot(4,1,2);
plot(t,Qp(:,2),'b','linewidth',2);
hold on;plot(t,q_dp(:,2),'-.m','linewidth',2);
grid;zoom;
xlabel('time in secs','fontweight','b'); 
ylabel('q2','fontweight','b')

subplot(4,1,3);
plot(t,Qp(:,3),'b','linewidth',2);
hold on;plot(t,q_dp(:,3),'-.m','linewidth',2);
grid;zoom;
xlabel('time in secs','fontweight','b');
ylabel('q3','fontweight','b')

subplot(4,1,4);
plot(t,Qp(:,4),'b','linewidth',2);
hold on;plot(t,q_dp(:,4),'-.m','linewidth',2);
grid;zoom;
xlabel('time in secs','fontweight','b');
ylabel('q4','fontweight','b')
```

[Figure looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADofz.jpg)

Is there any way to highlight like some transparent color in the background to identify the sunlit and eclipse portions in the above matlab figure.

Comment: You mean something like [*this*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkSRw.jpg)?

Comment: Yeah kind of like that and also it repeats

Comment: @Sardar Usama, Can you answer it in a better way? Referring to this [Highlight parts of matlab plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734086/highlight-parts-of-matlab-plot)

Comment: Define *better*.

Comment: Since using a for loop for data of amount 500k takes lots of time in matlab, how can one avoid using for loop?

Comment: How does that refer to the linked question? How much time is it taking for that large data, rough guess? Let me think if it can be vectorised

Comment: See a satellite to complete an orbit takes 5687 seconds. I'm saving data for every 128 ms i.e., for 5687 seconds the data generated will be of 44430 unit counts. Suppose I'm running for 10 orbits, it'll be 444300 counts of data. The 0's and 1's as explained in the question varies with respect to every orbit.

Comment: By time, I meant the time you mentioned in the first place i.e. time in matlab

Comment: Approx. 7 minutes for 10 orbits

Comment: For me, using 500k ,1 orbit takes ~10 sec. I doubt that you're timing the plotting and other stuff alongwith `patch`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`patch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) for this purpose. Adjust the loop according to your data.

```
plot(randperm(100));   hold on;    plot(randperm(100));  %plotting some random data      
%if sunlight remains for 20 units and 40 is the interval from which it repeats and
%100-20=80 is the last occurence then
for k=0:40:80  
    patch([k 20+k 20+k k], [0 0 100 100],'y','EdgeColor','none','FaceAlpha',0.3);
end
```

[image: output]