# How to set background in multiple colors in semilogy plot (MATLAB) ?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am looking for a way to shade the background of my semilog plot in two colors.
For example, in the following image, I have am plotting three polynomials and they all are equal at x=1. I want one rectangle for x<1 region and other for x>1 region. How can I insert two such rectangles, of different colors, in background to highlight these two regions.

MWE:

```
   x = 0.1:0.1:10;
   y1 = polyval([1, 0], x);      % Evaluate y = x;
   y2 = polyval([1, 0, 0], x);   % Evaluate y = x^2;
   y3 = polyval([1, 0, 0, 0], x);   % Evaluate y = x^3;    
   figure
   semilogy(x, y1, '.k', x, y2, '.b', x, y3, '.r');    title ('Three
   polynomials on a semilog y scale')    xlabel('x');    ylabel('y');   
   legend({'y= x', 'y = x^2', 'y = x^3'}, 'Location', 'Northwest')
```

[image]

Comment: Check these posts: [Transparent background for identification of 0 and 1 in a MATLAB figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527808/transparent-background-for-identification-of-0-and-1-in-a-matlab-figure) and [Highlight parts of matlab plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734086/highlight-parts-of-matlab-plot)

Comment: @SardarUsama Sorry, i typed the answer before seeing your comment. Indeed I follow the same path to solve, however when i searched, it was nothing with *logscale area*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve that using  [`area`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/area.html) or [`patch`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html).

As pointed by @SardarUsama, there are [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527808/transparent-background-for-identification-of-0-and-1-in-a-matlab-figure) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734086/highlight-parts-of-matlab-plot) with good examples on it, however, you need to avoid to have any zeros in the `area` data, otherwise it will fail.

Follows the code setting one area only.

```
x = 0.1:0.1:10;
y1 = polyval([1, 0], x);      % Evaluate y = x;
y2 = polyval([1, 0, 0], x);   % Evaluate y = x^2;
y3 = polyval([1, 0, 0, 0], x);   % Evaluate y = x^3;    
figure
plot(x, y1, '.k', x, y2, '.b', x, y3, '.r'); %MODIFIED   
hold on  %ADDED
title ('Three  polynomials on a semilog y scale')   
set (gca, 'Yscale', 'log'); %ADDED
xlabel('x');   
ylabel('y');   
legend({'y= x', 'y = x^2', 'y = x^3'}, 'Location', 'Northwest')

area( [1 1 10 10],[1e-3 1e+3 1e+3 1e-3 ],'FaceColor','green','facealpha',0.3)  %ADDED
```

The code above works for matlab after 2014b. If you have one before that, you can use the `patch` function (which requires some small change in the data, but uses the `Facealpha` option) or you can move the area to the background as i do below:

```
ax=get(gca,'Children'); %ADDED
set(gca,'Children',[ax(2) ax(3) ax(4) ax(1)]); %ADDED, move area to background
```

Note: Indeed, I missed the problem with the legend. I correct as mentioned, however for me the area was on top of the other graphs. To solve it i changed the order of the plots. If the area was with transparency, this will not be an issue.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work except the first two entries in legend are showing up as rectangles instead of lines.

Comment: @Guto use `area` after you're done plotting and with the `FaceAlpha` property. i.e  ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍`area([1,1,10,10],[1e-3,1e+3,1e+3,1e-3],'FaceColor','green','FaceAlpha',0.3)`

Comment: @SardarUsama Thanks, I'm using 2014b, so it does not work the `facealpha`. I edited the question considering both solutions.

Comment: @NAASI Indeed i missed, I correct with your idea and extra options to solve the transparency issue as well.